# Better bit operation for Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am generating some gradient pic with 10 bit data, and I have to mix it to 16 bit for compression purpose. I use this code but it's very slow. Is there any better way to do it?

```
def gradient_pic(num,f):
    pic = np.zeros(2580,dtype= np.uint8)
    pixvalue = np.random.randint(0,50,size=1,dtype=np.uint8)[0]
    for i in range (0,1544):
        for chunk in range(0,258):
            pic[chunk*5] = (pixvalue<<6)+((pixvalue+1)>>4)
            pic[chunk*5+1] = (((pixvalue+1)&15)<<12) + ((pixvalue+2)<<2)+ ((pixvalue+3)>>8)
            pic[chunk*5+2] = (((pixvalue+3)&255)<<8) + ((pixvalue+4)>>2)
            pic[chunk*5+3] = (((pixvalue+4)&3)<<14) + ((pixvalue+5)<<4)+ ((pixvalue+6)>>6)
            pic[chunk*5+4] = (((pixvalue+6)&63)<<10) + pixvalue+7
            pixvalue = (pixvalue+8)%1023
        f.write(pic)
    print(num)
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code? do you have some example input/output?

Comment: Since you're modifying pixvalue in your tight loop you cannot just make the loop in numpy. Have you considered `numba`? Maybe writing a ufunc (in c and compiled with numpy)?

Comment: pixvalue can be a fixed number. I tried to make it a constant value, it's still slow.

Comment: the same code I used in matlab,  it works fine there